# How do I allow webdriver js/ts to start zoom automatically without requiring user input?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver

When I write a js webdriver script to navigate to the zoom website, navigate to the page for a call, and click "Launch Meeting" button, I always see a popup:

```
This site is trying to open Zoom Meetings.

https://us04web.zoom.us wants to open this application

[ ] Always allow us04web.zoom.us to open links of this type in the associated app
```

https://shariktlt.blog/allow-open-external-protocol-chromedriver/ has the following instructions for java / Chrome, but the `setExperimentalOption` is not available on webdriver js:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put(
                "protocol_handler.allowed_origin_protocol_pairs",
                    singletonMap("https://us04web.zoom.us", singletonMap("zoommtg", true))
                );
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", singletonMap("protocol_handler.allowed_origin_protocol_pairs", singletonMap("https://us04web.zoom.us", singletonMap("zoommtg", true))));
 
 
 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

How can I achieve this for Edge / TS or JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me with webdriver 4.0.0, edgedriver 105:

```js
const edgeOptions = new Options()

edgeOptions.setUserPreferences({
  "protocol_handler": {
    "allowed_origin_protocol_pairs": {
      "https://us04web.zoom.us": { "zoommtg": true }
    }
  }
})

const webDriver = await new Builder().setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions).build()
```